# golang memory leak when break call net.LookupHost by time.After

Tags: go

I use this function to limit response time from DNS server

```
func LookupHost(hostname string, timeout time.Duration) ([]string, error) {
    c1 := make(chan []string)
    c2 := make(chan error)

    go func() {
        var ipaddr []string
        ipaddr, err := net.LookupHost(hostname)
        if err != nil {
            c2 <- err
            close(c2)
        }

        c1 <- ipaddr
        close(c1)
    }()

    select {
    case ipaddr := <-c1:
        return ipaddr, nil
    case err := <-c2:
        return []string{}, err
    case <-time.After(timeout):
        return []string{}, errors.New("timeout")
    }

}
```

The problem is that this function eat memory.
I think it is because I break `net.LookupHost(hostname)` syscall.

Any way to avoid this?
May be some other way how to query DNS servers with timeouts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check an alternative implementation proposed in [`bogdanovich/dns_resolver`](https://github.com/bogdanovich/dns_resolver)

Its [`dns_resolver.go`](https://github.com/bogdanovich/dns_resolver/blob/8c2aece5b6f59475aecb061a3734966975c42b11/dns_resolver.go) does include timeout management

```
resolver := dns_resolver.New([]string{"8.8.8.8", "8.8.4.4"})
// OR
// resolver := dns_resolver.NewFromResolvConf("resolv.conf")

// In case of i/o timeout
resolver.RetryTimes = 5
```

You can then wrap the all call in a goroutine, in order for the call to not break abruptly `net.LookupHost()`.

```
ip, err := resolver.LookupHost("google.com")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err.Error())
}
log.Println(ip)
// Output [216.58.192.46]
```